# How to allow a function to take in specified types?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, template-argument-deduction

So I want my function to take in a templated parameter, something like this:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T test)
```

I only want `foo` to take in all these types that I specify. Say I have something like `Image<cam1>`, `Image<cam2>`, `Other<cam1>`--> if I only want `Image<cam1>` and `Image<cam2>` to be types that go into `foo()`, how do I specify that?

Comment: C++20 will have concepts, so you can do this easily. With pre-C++20, you can use `std::enable_if` for this, using the technique SFINAE.

Comment: @geza sorry that is not very clear. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: Good reads: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae

Comment: Why do you want a templated parameter? Is there a pattern for which types you want to allow? (Being arbitrary with what you want is not necessarily bad, but it does kind of run contrary to typical reasons for using templates.)

Answer (score 2):

> if I only want `Image<cam1>` and `Image<cam2>` to be types that go into `foo`, how do I specify that?

Something as follows?

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, cam1>::value
                     || std::is_same<T, cam2>::value>::type foo (Image<T> test)
```

Comment: If there are a lot of places to be checked the same, provide it as an alias: `template<typename T>
using allowed_type = typename std::enable_if<
 std::is_same<T, cam1>::value ||
 std::is_same<T, cam2>::value>::type;` and use simply `allowed_type<T>`

Comment: Ok, what if the input is actually even more complicated...the input can also be templates such as `Image<settings1, cam1>`, `Image<settings2, cam2>`, etc...I tried doing `typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, <settings1, cam1>::value
                     || std::is_same<T, <settings2, cam2>::value>::type foo (Image<T> test)` but it doens't seem to compile

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58458464/2323908) by max66, especially if the set of allowed template parameters is used on more than one occasion (see to the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58458440/how-to-allow-a-function-to-take-in-specified-types#comment103260463_58458464) by Jejo). Another approach that doesn't use [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) is this:

```
namespace detail {
template <typename T>
void foo(Image<T> test) {}
}

void foo(Image<Cam1> test) { return detail::foo(test); }
void foo(Image<Cam2> test) { return detail::foo(test); }
```